# Is there any means by which I can generate and/or download a Witcher 1 Save file for import into The Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2, the-witcher

So, I'm *finally* getting around to playing The Witcher 2. (Yeah, yeah, I know, late to the party...). I've played the original Witcher, multiple times, and loved it. I had save files, that I was eagerly waiting to import. And then... I got a new computer.

I thought I had moved my save files over, but it turns out, I had tossed an empty folder named The Witcher with an empty subfolder named Saves onto my external HDD. Stupid mistake. Very stupid mistake.

Point is, I'd like to find a Witcher 1 save file suitable for importing. An ideal solution would be if there's some way to generate one with some key decisions made (I recall CDPR saying something about a web-based 'save generator at one point early in development, but I don't know if anything came of it?), or a database of them online (think, something like [Mass Effect Saves](http://www.masseffectsaves.com/)).

Barring that, if you have some save files with varying endgame choices (killed/spared monsters, Triss/Shani etc.) and paths (Order/Neutral/Scoia'tel), feel free to hit me up in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) -  I'll happily host the file and let you link it for an accepted answer if there's no better solution. If we get a bunch of people sending saves to me, a nice orderly CW answer could be a *great* resource.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just play through the Witcher 1 again? Should only take you an hour or two.

Comment: An hour or two? Really? *Have you played* the first Witcher game? *Do you remember, the goddamned Swamp?*

Answer (score 3):

Try this editor for Witcher 1 savegame files. It has an option for quests but im not completely sure what it allows you to do.

https://sites.google.com/site/ronsworkspace/GameUtilities/witcher

Here's a picture of it

http://www.d-log.info/savegame-editor.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I would downvote for not being a hardcore gamer but instead I figured it be of more help if I'd answer your question ;).

I've taken a quick glance, but as far as I can tell there's no equivalent site like Mass Effect Saves for Witcher 1 saves.

People tend to:

- Post on forums to ask for other users' savegames
- Use a generator to recreate a savegame

Arremer already provided you with an editor, and here's another one for you to try out. You should be able to make all decisions with this tool.

[Savegame editor over at WitcherVault](http://witchervault.ign.com/View.php?view=ToolsandUtilities.Detail&id=3)

Hope it helps!

Comment: May I ask why this was downvoted?